# How WCF client access nested object methods

Tags: wcf, object, nested

My WCF Service has API to create 'Employee' object which needs to be send to client app. This object has set of methods and properties. Now, client need to access Methods in order to set it's fields (API has few validation logics to set it's fields). How WCF service will send an custom object where client must be able to access methods.

Here the design is, my wcf service will provide a 'template' (from api) to client where in client uses this object methods to set/update fields and will send back to service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects you send and receive have logic associated to them (not a very good idea), you will need the assembly where those objects are impemented on both sides, since the metadata exposed by wcf only shows fields, and not methods.

I'd split that in two, keep the datacontracts clean and if you need validation logic, you can either do it in the wcf service and return errors to the client, or in the client, but that will extra logic to the client that you'll need to provide.

I'd go with validation logic in the server, and clean datacotracts. It's the best way to ensure your services are interoperable.

Comment: I am in the process of doing the same exactly. i.e. having assembly at both sides. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to return any objects from wcf service which contains any functions. Keep the data contract simple by having only fields (properties) , if any additional operation is needed make this available as part of operation contract.